# Very Slow Uninstalls in Jelly Bean

Tags: android

Ever since my Asus Transformer tablet was upgraded to Jelly Bean, I find that app and widget uninstalls are sometimes excruciatingly slow, as in taking several minutes instead of seconds. Could there be a reason for this?

The reason I'm posting this on Stackoverflow is that the apps I'm having the most trouble with are my own developed apps! As you know, when switching between debug and release builds of an app, you have to do an uninstall due to the different signing keys, so I do this on a regular basis and it's getting very annoying. Thanks for any hints on where to look for a solution -- if any.

Comment: any relevant logcat output to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue once, though it was in ICS and not Jelly Bean.  The problem in my case was Google's app "Currents" which generated thousands of files as part of its cache.  It took FOREVER to uninstall anything, or even get the size of any installed app because Android had to chug through all those thousands of files.  Google has since fixed Currents, by the way.

So, I would guess that it's a similar issue, one of your installed apps is going nuts with creating files.  If you open your app list and it takes a long time for the sizes to show up, that's further evidence that it's the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually just uninstalled Currents itself, mainly because I found it pretty useless. I'll take a look at the other apps and see what might be behind it.

Comment: Yes, it was Currents that was behind the entire slow behavior!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by SoundCloud's stream cache. After deleting it everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, also identified by extremely long time to calculate size of apps. In this case it was Google Earth App generating thousands of files (over 22000) on the local drive. Uninstalled that App 
and it was fixed.